# How to code a .CSS extract for this table using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am using Scrapy to build a recursive webscraper. The following is a for loop that works for extracting data from the table on the page linked below it:

```
rows = sel.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tbody//tr')

        for row in rows:

            print 'date:', "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'result:', "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_home:', "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_away:', "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'info:', "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip(), "".join( row.css('.info::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print 'rating:', "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'incidents:', ", ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print '-'*40
```

http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney

I am now trying to parse data from a different format of table on another part of the site, but I am struggling to work out how to code the .CSS for it. The table can be found here:

[http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Archive/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa](http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Show/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa)

The HTML for the first tab of this table is as follows:

```
<table id="team-squad-stats-summary-grid" class="grid with-centered-columns hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sortable rank" data-property="Rank" data-default-sort-dir="asc" title="Rank">R</th>
                    <th class="sortable rgn" data-property="PlayerRegionCode" data-default-sort-dir="asc" title="Country"></th>
                    <th class="sortable pn" data-property="PlayerName" data-default-sort-dir="asc" title="Player Name">Name</th>
                    <th class="sortable pos" data-property="RealPosition" data-default-sort-dir="asc" title="Position">Pos</th>
                    <th class="sortable age" data-property="Age" data-default-sort-dir="asc" title="Age">Age</th>
                    <th class="sortable hg" data-property="Height" title="Height">cm</th>
                    <th class="sortable wg" data-property="Weight" title="Weight">kg</th>

                    <th class="sortable ap" data-property="GameStarted"  title="First Eleven (Substitute)">Apps</th>
                    <th class="sortable g" data-property="Goals" title="Goals">Goal</th>
                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view  sortable a" data-property="Assists" title="Assists">A</th>
                    <th class="sortable y" data-property="Yellow" title="Yellow Cards">Yel</th>
                    <th class="sortable r" data-property="Red" title="Red Cards">Red</th>

                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view sortable spg" data-property="TotalShots" title="Shots per Game">SpG</th>
                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view sortable ps" data-property="PassSuccess" title="Pass success percentage">PS%</th>
                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view sortable aw" data-property="AerialWon" title="Aerial duels won per game">AW</th>
                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view sortable mom" data-property="ManOfTheMatch" title="Man of the Match">MoM</th>
                    <th class="in-squad-detailed-view sortable rating" data-property="Rating" title="Average Rating">Rt</th>    

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="team-squad-stats-summary-content"></tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="99" class="info">*Players shaded are players who are not currently active in team. (Loaned, sold, etc..)</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        </div>
```

I'm not sure of which elements of the HTML I should be using here or the syntax within .CSS. I have tried the following, but it has not worked:

```
for row in rows3:      

        rank = "".join( row.css('.rank::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
        playerregioncode = "".join( row.css('.playerregioncode a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
        playername = "".join( row.css('.name::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
        realposition = "".join( row.css('.realposition::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
        age = "".join( row.css('.age:text').extract() ).strip() + ','
        height = "".join( row.css('.height::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the second piece of code? Are you sure there's data in rows3?

Comment: @pgorsira no output is printed using this logic. rows3 resolves to a different table than the one used in the first example.

Comment: What selector are you using to populate rows3?

Comment: @pgorsira 'rows3 = sel.xpath('//table[@id="top-team-stats-summary-grid"]//tbody//tr')'

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for an id of "team-squad-stats-summary-grid"?

Comment: @pgorsira yes sorry, that was a typo. the data actually contained within the table seems to be referenced further down the html in black text, but im not sure how i would even begin to extract that.

Comment: I'm on the 2nd page you linked to but I don't see the html you pasted. I see a table with id "team-fixtures-summary". Is this what you're trying to scrape? If so what do you need out of it?

Comment: @pgorsira do control + f for find and then type 'team-squad-stats-summary-grid'. it is on row 556 of the html. ive only included six of the fields just as a demo, but eventually i want all the data on all of the tabs of that table...so every field of every tab. the data itself appears to be in a datastore instance further down the source code though.

Comment: What browser are you using? You're talking about the Israel-Maccabi-Haifi link right? In chrome I can't find anything with ctrl-F and line 556 is some javascript.

Comment: @pgorsira yes that is the correct link. i am using google chrome. line 556 is the javascript that defines the table (if i have read it right). further down the page at line 808 is the datastore that has the table data in it.

Comment: @pgorsira did you make sure you selected the 'history' tab of the table btw? it changes the html and javascript you can see when viewing the source code.

Comment: Does scrapy resolve Javascript? When I visited the website, I was not able to see any table at all (due to noscript). Only after allowing JS from some random IP address, I saw a table. But this did not have the mentioned `id="top-team-stats-summary-grid"` either.

Comment: While this isn't the answer you wanted - it's the one you need. Do what user3045351 said and use XPath. XPath is superior to CSS in so many ways that it boggles the mind why anyone would use CSS selectors outside of it's familiar because it's like javascript/html. At the root of it however - it's like bringing a knife to a nuclear bomb fight. XPath for victory.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would just parse the DataStore on line 808 (as you mentioned in the question comments). This is already in JSON format. So, to me, there is not really any need for scrapy here. Here's what I would do:

1. Grab the source of the page any way you like. For some reason, I cannot get the source using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It likely has to do with the JS mentioned in the comments on your question. I was, however, able to issue the below command in my shell and receive the source of the page. So, call this from python using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) or use something like [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

   curl http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Archive/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa
2. Find the text in the document between the first index of `DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams ,` and the next index of `);`. Let's call this string `data`.
3. Load the extracted string `data` into an array of python dictionaries:

   jdata = json.loads(data)

Now I believe `jdata` will have an array of dictionaries where each dictionary corresponds to one player. You can use each of these dictionaries to access the player's stats you're looking for in the original question.